# Specific buttons in Summernote (Indent and Outdent on main window)

Tags: summernote, bootswatch

In the Summernote wysiwyg editor, I want indent and outdent buttons on the main menu, but no paragraph options.

When creating an instance the buttons and popovers are defined in the following manner:

```
toolbar: [
['style', ['style']],
['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
['fontname', ['fontname']],
['color', ['color']],
['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
['height', ['height']],
['table', ['table']],
['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr']],
['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
['help', ['help']]
],
```

My problem is with the "paragraph" entry. Are the buttons in "paragraph" exposed in another way?

I would like something like this:

```
toolbar: [
['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'INDENT', 'OUTDENT']]
]
```

Is there access to these buttons somewhere? I have searched documentation to no avail. I hope you can save me some time before I crawl the code.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find the answer here?

Comment: Also interested in knowing the answer to this. Any luck?